# Nullpointer exception when saving datainto sharedpreferences

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

I am saving data into shared preferences inside of asynctask.In this asynctask i am downloading file from server.If i am downloading multiple files from server my first file is downloading is completed when my second file is started i am getting nullPointer exception.

I am  using fragments.My file downloading in Activity A,my download is in process i am changing activities in between downloading file.I am in activity B my file downloading is completed second file started here i am getting null pointer exception.Why?

i tried this :

Process 1 :

```
MyPreferences.saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "downloading",
                "process");
```

and 
Process 2 :

```
MyPreferences.saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences(
                MyFragment.this.getActivity(), "downloading",
                "process");
```

and

Process 3 :

```
 MyPreferences.saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences(
                getActivity(), "downloading",
                "process");
```

this methods are i am using inside onProgressUpdate.I am using Process 2&3 my context is null and i am getting nullpointerexception.And I am using Process 1 my context is not null but i am getting null pointer exception.

My preference method :

```
 public static void saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {
    System.out.println("context : "+context+" key : "+key +" value : "+value);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Why i am getting null pointer exception any one help me.

Edit #1 :

my logcat

```
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): at info.app.activity.FragmentActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(FragmentActivity.java:934)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at  info.app.activity.FragmentActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(FragmentActivity.java:1)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:647)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this exception i am getting when using Process 1.If i using Process 2&3 this exception i am getting

```
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): at info.app.preference.MyPreference.saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences(MyPreference.java:934)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): at info.app.activity.FragmentActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(FragmentActivity.java:934)
02-17 12:57:47.352: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at  info.app.activity.FragmentActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.onProgressUpdate(FragmentActivity.java:1)
```

this gives exception in saveDownloadingStatusIntoPreferences()

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
            MY_ST_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: post your logcat.. @Rajesh

Comment: Can you show the error message?? so that, its easy to understand

Comment: are u downloading in file in separate process

Comment: no i am not using any separate process.I am downloadin file by using URLConnection BufferInputStream and FileOutPutStream only.I just downloading normally.

Comment: Try using the following of your code only, to pinpoint the error: System.out.println("context : "+context+" key : "+key +" value : "+value); in your method.

Comment: @Rajesh: What is "MY_ST_PREFS" and where are you initializing it?